# How to make speech to text package to build?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, speech

I am trying to implement flutter package-speech to text, and get the below error. I am trying to make my app simply listen my speech and to print it to the console as of now to get it working.
The app will listen when I press the button

````
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          print("i am here");
                          bool available = await _speech!.initialize(
                              onError: ((errorNotification) =>
                                  print(errorNotification.errorMsg)),
                              onStatus: (val) {
                                print(val);
                              });
                          print("hello");
                          await _speech!.listen(
                              onResult: ((result) =>
                                  {print(result.recognizedWords)}));
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.mic)))```
Also, see below permissions
````

````
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>```


Can someone give me a hint to proceed further?
````